# OpenGL Lines with textures

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to create a electric lightning in OpenGl. For that I wrote this function:

```
public Blitz()
{
    points = new float[STEPS * 3];

    for(int i = 0; i < STEPS; i += 3)
    {
        points[i]     = (float) (startX + i * (endX - startX) / STEPS);
        points[i + 1] = (float) (startY + i * (endY - startY) / STEPS);
        points[i + 2] = 0;
    }

    // ...
    vertexBuffer.put(points);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

}

public void update()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < STEPS; i += 3)
    {
        float rnd = random(); // creates rnd float

        if(points[i] + rnd < startX + 5 && points[i] + rnd > startX - 5)
        {
            points[i] += rnd;
        }
    }

    vertexBuffer.clear();
    vertexBuffer.put(points);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void render()
{
    texture.bind();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    gl.glLineWidth(10);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, STEPS);
}
```

Here is my Texture Class that I use for my textures:

```
public class Texture 
{
    private GL10 gl;

    FloatBuffer texCoords;
    private int textureID;

    public Texture(GL10 gl, Bitmap bmp)
    {   
        this.gl = gl;

        int[] TextureIDs = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, TextureIDs, 0);     
        textureID = TextureIDs[0];

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, bmp, 0);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 4 * 2 * 4 );
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texCoords = buffer.asFloatBuffer(); 
        texCoords.put(0);
        texCoords.put(0);

        texCoords.put(0);
        texCoords.put(1);

        texCoords.put(1);
        texCoords.put(1);

        texCoords.put(1);
        texCoords.put(0);       
        texCoords.rewind();
    }

    public void bind()
    {   
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    }

    public void dispose()
    {
        int[] textures = {textureID};
        gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 0);
        textureID = 0;              
    }
}
```

With a normal color all works great but if I want to put this texture on the lines it comes to this result:

[image: Electric Texture]
[image: Result]

Do you have any ideas why? What is my mistake?

Comment: I do not see a single OpenGL API call in this code, all you have done is shown how you calculate a couple of points. Also you still have to texture-map line primitives the same way you would triangles, and I do not see any texture coordinates.

Comment: I added my texture class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is, that you assume, that a OpenGL line would be able to draw a texture with one coordinate varying perpendicular to the lines direction. OpenGL simply can't do that, because texture coordinates are vertex attributes and there are only two vertices to a line segment. Which means, that any texture coordinate variation is possible only along the line, not perpendicular to it.

The solution is not to draw a line, but a quad or a triangle strip with vertices being extruded to both sides of the line. This is most easily done using a shader operating in screen parallel space.

Comment: oh oky I thought this would be easy because I'm new to OpenGL. Of course I know how to draw a triangle but then the logic behind the drawing and the random coordinates are much more complex. Isn't there a function with which I can rotate the texture to the current angle of the line?

Comment: @Cilenco: No there is no such function. A line segment consists of only two vertices and only at the vertices some texture coordinates are assigned. Not that in theory you could use a fragment shader to determine for each rendered pixel the distance from the line center and use that as texture coordinate. But that requires that you do the whole transformation up to pixel based screen space in the vertex shader first. That's not too hard. **///** Anyway, OpenGL is not an API designed to be "easy" to use. It's more or less a sophisticated pencil to draw onto a canvas provided by the OS.

Comment: @Cilenco: The actual quality of the picture coming out, depends on how skillfully you're able in using that pencil.

Comment: Thank you but I have one question more: How can I remove the line from the last point to 0|0?

Comment: @Cilenco: Hard to tell from your code, because the part (probably) relevant for that problem is missing. However if I have to make an educated guess, you've got an off-by-1 bug in your code, i.e. you calculate your array lengths either by 1 element too short, or you pass OpenGL a length parameter too large by 1, and OpenGL then just takes uninitialized memory as actual data.